# Cross-compiling for mips under x86_64 with MSA support

Tags: mips, cross-compiling, simd, crosstool-ng

I’m trying to build a toolchain for cross-compiling for MIPS under x86 with crosstool-ng.
According to GCC 7.2.0 documentation it must support msa instructions. But when I’m building an application with assembly msa instructions using buit toolchain the application doesn’t execute and fails with "Illegal Instruction". What am I doing wrong?

I'm building the application with the following cflags: -mmsa, -mhard-float -mfp64, but without -mnan=2008, because in this case I got a problem with missing  gnu/stubs-o32_hard_2008.h
The text of .config file for croosstool-ng:

```
    #
    # Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT.
    # crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.23.0-288-gadaa3a5 Configuration
    #
    CT_CONFIGURE_has_static_link=y
    CT_CONFIGURE_has_wget=y
    CT_CONFIGURE_has_stat_flavor_GNU=y
    CT_CONFIGURE_has_make_3_81_or_newer=y
    CT_CONFIGURE_has_autoconf_2_63_or_newer=y
    CT_CONFIGURE_has_autoreconf_2_63_or_newer=y
    CT_CONFIGURE_has_automake_1_15_or_newer=y
    CT_CONFIGURE_has_gnu_m4_1_4_12_or_newer=y
    CT_CONFIGURE_has_git=y
    CT_MODULES=y

    #
    # Paths and misc options
    #

    #
    # crosstool-NG behavior
    #
    # CT_OBSOLETE is not set
    # CT_EXPERIMENTAL is not set
    # CT_DEBUG_CT is not set

    #
    # Paths
    #
    CT_LOCAL_TARBALLS_DIR="${HOME}/src"
    CT_SAVE_TARBALLS=y
    CT_WORK_DIR="${CT_TOP_DIR}/.build"
    CT_BUILD_TOP_DIR="${CT_WORK_DIR}/${CT_HOST:+HOST-${CT_HOST}/}${CT_TARGET}"
    CT_PREFIX_DIR="${CT_PREFIX:-${HOME}/x-tools}/${CT_HOST:+HOST-${CT_HOST}/}${CT_TARGET}"
    CT_RM_RF_PREFIX_DIR=y
    CT_REMOVE_DOCS=y
    CT_PREFIX_DIR_RO=y
    CT_STRIP_HOST_TOOLCHAIN_EXECUTABLES=y
    # CT_STRIP_TARGET_TOOLCHAIN_EXECUTABLES is not set

    #
    # Downloading
    #
    CT_DOWNLOAD_AGENT_WGET=y
    # CT_DOWNLOAD_AGENT_NONE is not set
    # CT_FORBID_DOWNLOAD is not set
    # CT_FORCE_DOWNLOAD is not set
    CT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10
    CT_DOWNLOAD_WGET_OPTIONS="--passive-ftp --tries=3 -nc --progress=dot:binary"
    # CT_ONLY_DOWNLOAD is not set
    # CT_USE_MIRROR is not set
    CT_VERIFY_DOWNLOAD_DIGEST=y
    CT_VERIFY_DOWNLOAD_DIGEST_SHA512=y

    CT_MAKE_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    # CT_VERIFY_DOWNLOAD_DIGEST_SHA256 is not set
    # CT_VERIFY_DOWNLOAD_DIGEST_SHA1 is not set
    # CT_VERIFY_DOWNLOAD_DIGEST_MD5 is not set
    CT_VERIFY_DOWNLOAD_DIGEST_ALG="sha512"
    # CT_VERIFY_DOWNLOAD_SIGNATURE is not set

    #
    # Extracting
    #
    # CT_FORCE_EXTRACT is not set
    CT_OVERRIDE_CONFIG_GUESS_SUB=y
    # CT_ONLY_EXTRACT is not set
    CT_PATCH_BUNDLED=y
    # CT_PATCH_BUNDLED_LOCAL is not set
    CT_PATCH_ORDER="bundled"

    #
    # Build behavior
    #
    CT_PARALLEL_JOBS=0
    CT_LOAD=""
    CT_USE_PIPES=y
    CT_EXTRA_CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=""
    CT_EXTRA_LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=""
    CT_EXTRA_CFLAGS_FOR_HOST=""
    CT_EXTRA_LDFLAGS_FOR_HOST=""
    # CT_CONFIG_SHELL_SH is not set
    # CT_CONFIG_SHELL_ASH is not set
    CT_CONFIG_SHELL_BASH=y
    # CT_CONFIG_SHELL_CUSTOM is not set
    CT_CONFIG_SHELL="${bash}"

    #
    # Logging
    #
    # CT_LOG_ERROR is not set
    # CT_LOG_WARN is not set
    # CT_LOG_INFO is not set
    CT_LOG_EXTRA=y
    # CT_LOG_ALL is not set
    # CT_LOG_DEBUG is not set
    CT_LOG_LEVEL_MAX="EXTRA"
    # CT_LOG_SEE_TOOLS_WARN is not set
    CT_LOG_PROGRESS_BAR=y
    CT_LOG_TO_FILE=y
    CT_MAKE_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    СT_LOG_FILE_COMPRESS=y

    #
    # Target options
    #
    # CT_ARCH_ALPHA is not set
    # CT_ARCH_ARM is not set
    # CT_ARCH_AVR is not set
    # CT_ARCH_M68K is not set
    CT_ARCH_MIPS=y
    # CT_ARCH_NIOS2 is not set
    # CT_ARCH_POWERPC is not set
    # CT_ARCH_S390 is not set
    # CT_ARCH_SH is not set
    # CT_ARCH_SPARC is not set
    # CT_ARCH_X86 is not set
    # CT_ARCH_XTENSA is not set
    CT_ARCH="mips"
    CT_ARCH_CHOICE_KSYM="MIPS"
    CT_ARCH_TUNE=""
    CT_ARCH_MIPS_PKG_KSYM=""
    CT_ARCH_mips_o32=y
    CT_ARCH_mips_ABI="32"
    CT_ARCH_SUFFIX=""

    #
    # Generic target options
    #
    # CT_MULTILIB is not set
    CT_DEMULTILIB=y
    CT_ARCH_USE_MMU=y
    CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_EITHER_ENDIAN=y
    CT_ARCH_DEFAULT_BE=y
    CT_ARCH_BE=y
    # CT_ARCH_LE is not set
    # CT_ARCH_BE_LE is not set
    # CT_ARCH_LE_BE is not set
    CT_ARCH_ENDIAN="big"
    CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_32=y
    CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_64=y
    CT_ARCH_DEFAULT_32=y
    CT_ARCH_BITNESS=32
    CT_ARCH_32=y
    # CT_ARCH_64 is not set

    #
    # Target optimisations
    #
    CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_ARCH=y
    CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_TUNE=y
    CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_FLOAT=y
    CT_ARCH_ARCH="mips32r5"
    # CT_ARCH_FLOAT_AUTO is not set
    CT_ARCH_FLOAT_HW=y
    # CT_ARCH_FLOAT_SW is not set
    CT_TARGET_CFLAGS=""
    CT_TARGET_LDFLAGS=""
    CT_ARCH_FLOAT="hard"

    #
    # Toolchain options
    #

    #
    # General toolchain options
    #
    CT_FORCE_SYSROOT=y
    CT_USE_SYSROOT=y
    CT_SYSROOT_NAME="sysroot"
    CT_SYSROOT_DIR_PREFIX=""
    CT_WANTS_STATIC_LINK=y
    CT_WANTS_STATIC_LINK_CXX=y
    # CT_STATIC_TOOLCHAIN is not set
    CT_SHOW_CT_VERSION=y
    CT_TOOLCHAIN_PKGVERSION=""
    CT_TOOLCHAIN_BUGURL=""

    #
    # Tuple completion and aliasing
    #
    CT_TARGET_VENDOR="unknown"
    CT_TARGET_ALIAS_SED_EXPR=""
    CT_TARGET_ALIAS=""

    #
    # Toolchain type
    #
    CT_CROSS=y
    # CT_CANADIAN is not set
    CT_TOOLCHAIN_TYPE="cross"

    #
    # Build system
    #
    CT_BUILD=""
    CT_BUILD_PREFIX=""
    CT_BUILD_SUFFIX=""

    #
    # Misc options
    #
    # CT_TOOLCHAIN_ENABLE_NLS is not set

    #
    # Operating System
    #
    CT_KERNEL_SUPPORTS_SHARED_LIBS=y
    # CT_KERNEL_BARE_METAL is not set
    CT_KERNEL_LINUX=y
    CT_KERNEL="linux"
    CT_KERNEL_CHOICE_KSYM="LINUX"
    CT_KERNEL_LINUX_PKG_KSYM="LINUX"
    CT_LINUX_DIR_NAME="linux"
    CT_LINUX_PKG_NAME="linux"
    CT_LINUX_SRC_RELEASE=y
    # CT_LINUX_V_4_14 is not set
    # CT_LINUX_V_4_13 is not set
    # CT_LINUX_V_4_12 is not set
    # CT_LINUX_V_4_11 is not set
    # CT_LINUX_V_4_10 is not set
    # CT_LINUX_V_4_9 is not set
    CT_LINUX_V_4_4=y
    # CT_LINUX_V_4_1 is not set
    # CT_LINUX_V_3_16 is not set
    # CT_LINUX_V_3_13 is not set
    # CT_LINUX_V_3_12 is not set
    # CT_LINUX_V_3_10 is not set
    # CT_LINUX_V_3_4 is not set
    # CT_LINUX_V_3_2 is not set
    CT_LINUX_VERSION="4.4.103"
    CT_LINUX_MIRRORS="$(CT_Mirrors kernel.org linux ${CT_LINUX_VERSION})"
    CT_LINUX_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_LINUX_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_LINUX_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.xz .tar.gz"
    CT_LINUX_SIGNATURE_FORMAT="unpacked/.sign"
    CT_LINUX_3_2_or_later=y
    CT_LINUX_REQUIRE_3_2_or_later=y
    CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSITY_0=y
    # CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSITY_1 is not set
    # CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSITY_2 is not set
    CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSE_LEVEL=0
    CT_KERNEL_LINUX_INSTALL_CHECK=y

    #
    # Common kernel options
    #
    CT_SHARED_LIBS=y

    #
    # Binary utilities
    #
    CT_ARCH_BINFMT_ELF=y
    CT_BINUTILS_BINUTILS=y
    CT_BINUTILS="binutils"
    CT_BINUTILS_CHOICE_KSYM="BINUTILS"
    CT_BINUTILS_BINUTILS_PKG_KSYM="BINUTILS"
    CT_BINUTILS_DIR_NAME="binutils"
    CT_BINUTILS_USE_GNU=y
    CT_BINUTILS_USE="BINUTILS"
    CT_BINUTILS_PKG_NAME="binutils"
    CT_BINUTILS_SRC_RELEASE=y
    # CT_BINUTILS_V_2_29_1 is not set
    # CT_BINUTILS_V_2_28_1 is not set
    # CT_BINUTILS_V_2_27 is not set
    CT_BINUTILS_V_2_26_1=y
    CT_BINUTILS_VERSION="2.26.1"
    CT_BINUTILS_MIRRORS="$(CT_Mirrors GNU binutils) $(CT_Mirrors sourceware binutils/releases)"
    CT_BINUTILS_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_BINUTILS_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_BINUTILS_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.bz2 .tar.gz"
    CT_BINUTILS_SIGNATURE_FORMAT="packed/.sig"
    CT_BINUTILS_2_25_or_later=y
    CT_BINUTILS_REQUIRE_2_25_or_later=y
    CT_BINUTILS_2_23_or_later=y

    #
    # GNU binutils
    #
    CT_BINUTILS_HAS_HASH_STYLE=y
    CT_BINUTILS_HAS_GOLD=y
    CT_BINUTILS_HAS_PLUGINS=y
    CT_BINUTILS_HAS_PKGVERSION_BUGURL=y
    CT_BINUTILS_FORCE_LD_BFD_DEFAULT=y
    CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_LD=y
    CT_BINUTILS_LINKERS_LIST="ld"
    CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_DEFAULT="bfd"
    # CT_BINUTILS_PLUGINS is not set
    CT_BINUTILS_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
    # CT_BINUTILS_FOR_TARGET is not set

    #
    # C-library
    #
    CT_LIBC_GLIBC=y
    # CT_LIBC_UCLIBC is not set
    CT_LIBC="glibc"
    CT_LIBC_CHOICE_KSYM="GLIBC"
    CT_THREADS="nptl"
    CT_LIBC_GLIBC_PKG_KSYM="GLIBC"
    CT_GLIBC_DIR_NAME="glibc"
    CT_GLIBC_USE_GNU=y
    CT_GLIBC_USE="GLIBC"
    CT_GLIBC_PKG_NAME="glibc"
    CT_GLIBC_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_GLIBC_V_2_26=y
    # CT_GLIBC_V_2_25 is not set
    # CT_GLIBC_V_2_24 is not set
    # CT_GLIBC_V_2_23 is not set
    # CT_GLIBC_V_2_19 is not set
    # CT_GLIBC_V_2_17 is not set
    # CT_GLIBC_V_2_12_1 is not set
    CT_GLIBC_VERSION="2.26"
    CT_GLIBC_MIRRORS="$(CT_Mirrors GNU glibc)"
    CT_GLIBC_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_GLIBC_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_GLIBC_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.xz .tar.bz2 .tar.gz"
    CT_GLIBC_SIGNATURE_FORMAT="packed/.sig"
    CT_GLIBC_2_26_or_later=y
    CT_GLIBC_2_26_or_older=y
    CT_GLIBC_2_24_or_later=y
    CT_GLIBC_2_23_or_later=y
    CT_GLIBC_2_20_or_later=y
    CT_GLIBC_2_17_or_later=y
    CT_GLIBC_2_14_or_later=y
    CT_GLIBC_DEP_KERNEL_HEADERS_VERSION=y
    CT_GLIBC_DEP_BINUTILS=y
    CT_GLIBC_DEP_GCC=y
    CT_GLIBC_HAS_LIBIDN_ADDON=y
    # CT_GLIBC_USE_LIBIDN_ADDON is not set
    CT_GLIBC_NO_SPARC_V8=y
    CT_GLIBC_HAS_OBSOLETE_RPC=y
    CT_GLIBC_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
    CT_GLIBC_CONFIGPARMS=""
    CT_GLIBC_EXTRA_CFLAGS=""
    CT_GLIBC_ENABLE_OBSOLETE_RPC=y
    # CT_GLIBC_DISABLE_VERSIONING is not set
    CT_GLIBC_OLDEST_ABI=""
    CT_GLIBC_FORCE_UNWIND=y
    # CT_GLIBC_LOCALES is not set
    # CT_GLIBC_KERNEL_VERSION_NONE is not set
    CT_GLIBC_KERNEL_VERSION_AS_HEADERS=y
    # CT_GLIBC_KERNEL_VERSION_CHOSEN is not set
    CT_GLIBC_MIN_KERNEL="4.4.103"
    CT_LIBC_SUPPORT_THREADS_ANY=y
    CT_LIBC_SUPPORT_THREADS_NATIVE=y

    #
    # Common C library options
    #
    CT_THREADS_NATIVE=y
    # CT_CREATE_LDSO_CONF is not set
    CT_LIBC_XLDD=y

    #
    # C compiler
    #
    CT_CC_CORE_PASSES_NEEDED=y
    CT_CC_CORE_PASS_1_NEEDED=y
    CT_CC_CORE_PASS_2_NEEDED=y
    CT_CC_SUPPORT_CXX=y
    CT_CC_SUPPORT_FORTRAN=y
    CT_CC_SUPPORT_ADA=y
    CT_CC_SUPPORT_OBJC=y
    CT_CC_SUPPORT_OBJCXX=y
    CT_CC_SUPPORT_GOLANG=y
    CT_CC_GCC=y
    CT_CC="gcc"
    CT_CC_CHOICE_KSYM="GCC"
    CT_CC_GCC_PKG_KSYM="GCC"
    CT_GCC_DIR_NAME="gcc"
    CT_GCC_USE_GNU=y
    CT_GCC_USE="GCC"
    CT_GCC_PKG_NAME="gcc"
    CT_GCC_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_GCC_V_7_2_0=y
    # CT_GCC_V_6_4_0 is not set
    # CT_GCC_V_5_5_0 is not set
    # CT_GCC_V_4_9_4 is not set
    CT_GCC_VERSION="7.2.0"
    CT_GCC_MIRRORS="$(CT_Mirrors GNU gcc/gcc-${CT_GCC_VERSION}) $(CT_Mirrors sourceware gcc/releases/gcc-${CT_GCC_VERSION})"
    CT_GCC_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_GCC_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_GCC_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.xz .tar.gz"
    CT_GCC_SIGNATURE_FORMAT=""
    CT_GCC_7_or_later=y
    CT_GCC_6_or_later=y
    CT_GCC_5_or_later=y
    CT_GCC_4_9_2_or_later=y
    CT_GCC_4_9_or_later=y
    CT_GCC_REQUIRE_4_9_or_later=y
    CT_GCC_4_8_or_later=y
    CT_CC_GCC_HAS_LIBMPX=y
    CT_CC_GCC_ENABLE_CXX_FLAGS=""
    CT_CC_GCC_CORE_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
    CT_CC_GCC_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
    CT_CC_GCC_STATIC_LIBSTDCXX=y
    # CT_CC_GCC_SYSTEM_ZLIB is not set
    CT_CC_GCC_CONFIG_TLS=m

    #
    # Optimisation features
    #
    CT_CC_GCC_USE_GRAPHITE=y
    CT_CC_GCC_USE_LTO=y

    #
    # Settings for libraries running on target
    #
    CT_CC_GCC_ENABLE_TARGET_OPTSPACE=y
    # CT_CC_GCC_LIBMUDFLAP is not set
    # CT_CC_GCC_LIBGOMP is not set
    # CT_CC_GCC_LIBSSP is not set
    # CT_CC_GCC_LIBQUADMATH is not set
    # CT_CC_GCC_LIBSANITIZER is not set

    #
    # Misc. obscure options.
    #
    CT_CC_CXA_ATEXIT=y
    # CT_CC_GCC_DISABLE_PCH is not set
    CT_CC_GCC_SJLJ_EXCEPTIONS=m
    CT_CC_GCC_LDBL_128=m
    # CT_CC_GCC_BUILD_ID is not set
    CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_DEFAULT=y
    # CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_SYSV is not set
    # CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_GNU is not set
    # CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_BOTH is not set
    CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE=""
    CT_CC_GCC_DEC_FLOAT_AUTO=y
    # CT_CC_GCC_DEC_FLOAT_BID is not set
    # CT_CC_GCC_DEC_FLOAT_DPD is not set
    # CT_CC_GCC_DEC_FLOATS_NO is not set
    CT_CC_GCC_HAS_ARCH_OPTIONS=y

    #
    # archictecture-specific options
    #
    CT_CC_GCC_mips_llsc=m
    CT_CC_GCC_mips_synci=m
    # CT_CC_GCC_mips_plt is not set

    #
    # Additional supported languages:
    #
    CT_CC_LANG_CXX=y
    CT_CC_LANG_FORTRAN=y

    #
    # Debug facilities
    #
    # CT_DEBUG_DUMA is not set
    CT_DEBUG_GDB=y
    CT_DEBUG_GDB_PKG_KSYM="GDB"
    CT_GDB_DIR_NAME="gdb"
    CT_GDB_USE_GNU=y
    CT_GDB_USE="GDB"
    CT_GDB_PKG_NAME="gdb"
    CT_GDB_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_GDB_V_8_0_1=y
    # CT_GDB_V_7_12_1 is not set
    # CT_GDB_V_7_11_1 is not set
    CT_GDB_VERSION="8.0.1"
    CT_GDB_MIRRORS="$(CT_Mirrors GNU gdb) $(CT_Mirrors sourceware gdb/releases)"
    CT_GDB_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_GDB_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_GDB_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.xz .tar.gz"
    CT_GDB_SIGNATURE_FORMAT=""
    CT_GDB_8_0_or_later=y
    CT_GDB_7_2_or_later=y
    CT_GDB_7_0_or_later=y
    CT_GDB_CROSS=y
    # CT_GDB_CROSS_STATIC is not set
    # CT_GDB_CROSS_SIM is not set
    CT_GDB_CROSS_PYTHON=y
    CT_GDB_CROSS_PYTHON_BINARY=""
    CT_GDB_CROSS_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
    # CT_GDB_NATIVE is not set
    CT_GDB_GDBSERVER=y
    CT_GDB_GDBSERVER_HAS_IPA_LIB=y
    # CT_GDB_GDBSERVER_STATIC_LIBSTDCXX is not set
    # CT_GDB_GDBSERVER_BUILD_IPA_LIB is not set
    CT_GDB_HAS_PKGVERSION_BUGURL=y
    CT_GDB_HAS_PYTHON=y
    CT_GDB_INSTALL_GDBINIT=y
    # CT_DEBUG_LTRACE is not set
    # CT_DEBUG_STRACE is not set

    #
    # Companion libraries
    #
    # CT_COMPLIBS_CHECK is not set
    # CT_COMP_LIBS_CLOOG is not set
    CT_COMP_LIBS_EXPAT=y
    CT_COMP_LIBS_EXPAT_PKG_KSYM="EXPAT"
    CT_EXPAT_DIR_NAME="expat"
    CT_EXPAT_PKG_NAME="expat"
    CT_EXPAT_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_EXPAT_V_2_2_5=y
    CT_EXPAT_VERSION="2.2.5"
    CT_EXPAT_MIRRORS="http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/expat/expat/${CT_EXPAT_VERSION}"
    CT_EXPAT_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_EXPAT_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_EXPAT_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.bz2"
    CT_EXPAT_SIGNATURE_FORMAT=""
    CT_COMP_LIBS_GETTEXT=y
    CT_COMP_LIBS_GETTEXT_PKG_KSYM="GETTEXT"
    CT_GETTEXT_DIR_NAME="gettext"
    CT_GETTEXT_PKG_NAME="gettext"
    CT_GETTEXT_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_GETTEXT_V_0_19_8_1=y
    CT_GETTEXT_VERSION="0.19.8.1"
    CT_GETTEXT_MIRRORS="$(CT_Mirrors GNU gettext)"
    CT_GCC_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_GCC_V_7_2_0=y
    CT_GETTEXT_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_GETTEXT_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_GETTEXT_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.xz .tar.lz .tar.gz"
    CT_GETTEXT_SIGNATURE_FORMAT="packed/.sig"
    CT_COMP_LIBS_GMP=y
    CT_COMP_LIBS_GMP_PKG_KSYM="GMP"
    CT_GMP_DIR_NAME="gmp"
    CT_GMP_PKG_NAME="gmp"
    CT_GMP_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_GMP_V_6_1_2=y
    CT_GMP_VERSION="6.1.2"
    CT_GMP_MIRRORS="https://gmplib.org/download/gmp https://gmplib.org/download/gmp/archive $(CT_Mirrors GNU gmp)"
    CT_GMP_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_GMP_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_GMP_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.xz .tar.lz .tar.bz2"
    CT_GMP_SIGNATURE_FORMAT="packed/.sig"
    CT_GMP_5_1_or_later=y
    CT_COMP_LIBS_ISL=y
    CT_COMP_LIBS_ISL_PKG_KSYM="ISL"
    CT_ISL_DIR_NAME="isl"
    CT_ISL_PKG_NAME="isl"
    CT_ISL_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_GCC_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_GCC_V_7_2_0=y
    CT_ISL_V_0_18=y
    # CT_ISL_V_0_17_1 is not set
    # CT_ISL_V_0_16_1 is not set
    # CT_ISL_V_0_15 is not set
    CT_ISL_VERSION="0.18"
    CT_ISL_MIRRORS="http://isl.gforge.inria.fr"
    CT_ISL_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_ISL_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_ISL_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.xz .tar.bz2 .tar.gz"
    CT_ISL_SIGNATURE_FORMAT=""
    CT_ISL_0_15_or_later=y
    CT_ISL_REQUIRE_0_15_or_later=y
    CT_ISL_0_14_or_later=y
    CT_ISL_REQUIRE_0_14_or_later=y
    CT_ISL_0_13_or_later=y
    CT_ISL_0_12_or_later=y
    CT_ISL_REQUIRE_0_12_or_later=y
    # CT_COMP_LIBS_LIBELF is not set
    CT_COMP_LIBS_LIBICONV=y
    CT_COMP_LIBS_LIBICONV_PKG_KSYM="LIBICONV"
    CT_LIBICONV_DIR_NAME="libiconv"
    CT_LIBICONV_PKG_NAME="libiconv"
    CT_LIBICONV_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_LIBICONV_V_1_15=y
    CT_LIBICONV_VERSION="1.15"
    CT_LIBICONV_MIRRORS="$(CT_Mirrors GNU libiconv)"
    CT_LIBICONV_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_LIBICONV_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_LIBICONV_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.gz"
    CT_LIBICONV_SIGNATURE_FORMAT="packed/.sig"
    CT_COMP_LIBS_MPC=y
    CT_COMP_LIBS_MPC_PKG_KSYM="MPC"
    CT_MPC_DIR_NAME="mpc"
    CT_MPC_PKG_NAME="mpc"
    CT_MPC_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_MPC_V_1_0_3=y
    CT_GCC_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_GCC_V_7_2_0=y
    CT_MPC_VERSION="1.0.3"
    CT_MPC_MIRRORS="http://www.multiprecision.org/mpc/download $(CT_Mirrors GNU mpc)"
    CT_MPC_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_MPC_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_MPC_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.gz"
    CT_MPC_SIGNATURE_FORMAT="packed/.sig"
    CT_COMP_LIBS_MPFR=y
    CT_COMP_LIBS_MPFR_PKG_KSYM="MPFR"
    CT_MPFR_DIR_NAME="mpfr"
    CT_MPFR_PKG_NAME="mpfr"
    CT_MPFR_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_MPFR_V_3_1_6=y
    CT_MPFR_VERSION="3.1.6"
    CT_MPFR_MIRRORS="http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-${CT_MPFR_VERSION} $(CT_Mirrors GNU mpfr)"
    CT_MPFR_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_MPFR_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_MPFR_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.xz .tar.bz2 .tar.gz .zip"
    CT_MPFR_SIGNATURE_FORMAT="packed/.asc"
    CT_COMP_LIBS_NCURSES=y
    CT_COMP_LIBS_NCURSES_PKG_KSYM="NCURSES"
    CT_NCURSES_DIR_NAME="ncurses"
    CT_NCURSES_PKG_NAME="ncurses"
    CT_NCURSES_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_NCURSES_V_6_0=y
    CT_NCURSES_VERSION="6.0"
    CT_NCURSES_MIRRORS="ftp://invisible-island.net/ncurses $(CT_Mirrors GNU ncurses)"
    CT_NCURSES_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_NCURSES_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_NCURSES_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.gz"
    CT_NCURSES_SIGNATURE_FORMAT="packed/.sig"
    CT_NCURSES_HOST_CONFIG_ARGS=""
    CT_NCURSES_HOST_DISABLE_DB=y
    CT_NCURSES_HOST_FALLBACKS="linux,xterm,xterm-color,xterm-256color,vt100"
    CT_NCURSES_TARGET_CONFIG_ARGS=""
    # CT_NCURSES_TARGET_DISABLE_DB is not set
    CT_NCURSES_TARGET_FALLBACKS=""
    # CT_COMP_LIBS_ZLIB is not set
    CT_LIBICONV_NEEDED=y
    CT_GETTEXT_NEEDED=y
    CT_GMP_NEEDED=y
    CT_MPFR_NEEDED=y
    CT_ISL_NEEDED=y
    CT_MPC_NEEDED=y
    CT_EXPAT_NEEDED=y
    CT_NCURSES_NEEDED=y
    # CT_ZLIB_NEEDED is not set
    CT_LIBICONV=y
    CT_GETTEXT=y
    CT_GMP=y
    CT_MPFR=y
    CT_ISL=y
    CT_MPC=y
    CT_EXPAT=y
    CT_NCURSES=y

    #
    # Companion tools
    #
    # CT_COMP_TOOLS_FOR_HOST is not set
    CT_COMP_TOOLS_AUTOCONF=y
    CT_COMP_TOOLS_AUTOCONF_PKG_KSYM="AUTOCONF"
    CT_AUTOCONF_DIR_NAME="autoconf"
    CT_AUTOCONF_PKG_NAME="autoconf"
    CT_AUTOCONF_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_AUTOCONF_V_2_69=y
    # CT_AUTOCONF_V_2_65 is not set
    CT_AUTOCONF_VERSION="2.69"
    CT_AUTOCONF_MIRRORS="$(CT_Mirrors GNU autoconf)"
    CT_AUTOCONF_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_AUTOCONF_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_AUTOCONF_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.xz .tar.gz"
    CT_AUTOCONF_SIGNATURE_FORMAT="packed/.sig"
    CT_COMP_TOOLS_AUTOMAKE=y
    CT_COMP_TOOLS_AUTOMAKE_PKG_KSYM="AUTOMAKE"
    CT_AUTOMAKE_DIR_NAME="automake"
    CT_AUTOMAKE_PKG_NAME="automake"
    CT_AUTOMAKE_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_AUTOMAKE_V_1_15_1=y
    CT_AUTOMAKE_VERSION="1.15.1"
    CT_AUTOMAKE_MIRRORS="$(CT_Mirrors GNU automake)"
    CT_AUTOMAKE_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_AUTOMAKE_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_AUTOMAKE_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.xz .tar.gz"
    CT_AUTOMAKE_SIGNATURE_FORMAT="packed/.sig"
    CT_COMP_TOOLS_LIBTOOL=y
    CT_COMP_TOOLS_LIBTOOL_PKG_KSYM="LIBTOOL"
    CT_LIBTOOL_DIR_NAME="libtool"
    CT_LIBTOOL_PKG_NAME="libtool"
    CT_LIBTOOL_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_LIBTOOL_V_2_4_6=y
    CT_LIBTOOL_VERSION="2.4.6"
    CT_LIBTOOL_MIRRORS="$(CT_Mirrors GNU libtool)"
    CT_LIBTOOL_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_LIBTOOL_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_LIBTOOL_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.xz .tar.gz"
    CT_LIBTOOL_SIGNATURE_FORMAT="packed/.sig"
    # CT_COMP_TOOLS_M4 is not set
    CT_COMP_TOOLS_MAKE=y
    CT_COMP_TOOLS_MAKE_PKG_KSYM="MAKE"
    CT_MAKE_DIR_NAME="make"
    CT_MAKE_PKG_NAME="make"
    CT_MAKE_SRC_RELEASE=y
    CT_MAKE_V_4_2_1=y
    CT_MAKE_VERSION="4.2.1"
    CT_MAKE_MIRRORS="$(CT_Mirrors GNU make)"
    CT_MAKE_ARCHIVE_FILENAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_MAKE_ARCHIVE_DIRNAME="@{pkg_name}-@{version}"
    CT_MAKE_ARCHIVE_FORMATS=".tar.bz2 .tar.gz"
    CT_MAKE_SIGNATURE_FORMAT="packed/.sig"
    # CT_MAKE_GMAKE_SYMLINK is not set
```

Comment: Which actual instruction faults?  Use `gdb` on your MIPS system to find out.  Are you sure your MIPS hardware is supposed to support that instruction?

Comment: I got no gdb-server on my mips. I got mispr5, so it should support msa. Moreover, it does support it but when I’m using compiler from mips toolchain.

Comment: Does your kernel log the address of the fault?  Or produce a core-dump?

Comment: No. But the problem is exactly with assembler msa instruction. The applications with regular c-instructions applied to vector data types and assembler instructions with regular data types are executed successfully.

Comment: But you said you could use MSA instructions with a different toolchain.  So finding the instruction address could point you to something weird, like a wrong machine encoding.  It gives you a specific place to look in detail for weirdness, or to diff between the outputs of the two toolchains.  Did MIPS32r5 change the machine encoding for any of the instructions you're using?

Comment: I don't know how to find out the address of faulting instruction, really. I tried to diassemble these application with objdump, so they are different, as excpected. But the msa instructions look the same, except their addresses

Comment: Let it dump core, then you can use gdb on another machine to examine the executable + core file and see the state of registers (including the program counter).  The whole point of core dumps is debugging on a different machine.  Maybe something is causing a jump to a bogus address that wasn't even supposed to be an instruction; checking with gdb will rule that out.  To enable core files, use `ulimit -c unlimited`, and/or tweak `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` if it was set to pipe into `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump`.  Or change systemd-coredump settings or whatever.

Comment: The analysis of core dump file has shown the following result:
`Program terminated with signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
#0  0x00400504 in ?? ()`
Command `x/16i $pc` given to gdb confirmed that the problem is with msa instruction:
`0x400504: ld.w $w1,0(t2)`

Comment: And the exact same instruction-word doesn't fault when it runs as part of the non-cross-compiled binary?  Maybe it includes some startup code that enables something MSA needs for instructions to not fault?  I don't know anything about MSA specifically, just how to debug in general.